# What should I add to make this output Undefined?

Tags: java

Can someone help me on what code I should add for when the answer is Undefined it will display "Undefined"

Ex. 2/0 the answer will output Undefined

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SimpleCalcu
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    int n1,n2;
    String operation;

    Scanner v  = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please Enter The First Number");
    n1 = v.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please Enter The Second Number");
    n2 = v.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please Enter The Operation");
    operation = v.next();
    v.close();

    if (operation.equals("+"))
    {
        System.out.println("Your Answer is "+(n1 + n2));
    }
    else if (operation.equals("-"))
    {
        System.out.println("Your Answer is "+(n1 - n2));
    }       
    else if (operation.equals("*"))
    {
        System.out.println("Your Answer is "+(n1 * n2));
    }   
    else if (operation.equals("/"))
    {
        System.out.println("Your Answer is "+(n1 / n2));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use descriptive question titles.

Comment: Okieee Let me edit it :) thanks

Comment: Inside `if (operation.equals("/"))` add another `if` which will check if `n2` is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the conditional check for `n2 == 0` and print the message.

```
else if (operation.equals("/"))
{
  if(n2 == 0) {
    System.out.println("Undefined");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Your Answer is " + (n1 / n2));
  }
}
```

Comment: @Captain Can you provide the case where it is not working?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you really meant.:( I'm hoping if u can give me what I should add exactly I think I dont understand fully :)

Comment: @Captain I have provided the code snippet, You need to replace the `else if` for division operation.

Comment: I understand it now and I got it TYSM for your wonderful help and support :)

Comment: @Captain You can accept the answer, if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

*Do something likewise into you code,*

```
else if (operation.equals("/"))
    {
       System.out.println((n2==0)?"Undefined":"Your Answer is :"+(n1 / n2));
    }
```

> It will protect you from getting ArithmaticException while Divider
>   gets zero,
>
> It means while 'n2' getting zero simply prints "Undefined"